# Change number notification on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp

If I change my number on WhatsApp through Change Number feature, will the people that I chatted with be notified in their personal Chat Windows with me that I have changed my number or is it only notified in Group Chats?

If there is no notification, will the my number automatically changed to the new number seeing from the point of view of those people who chatted with me (when they open the chat windows)?

What if one of those people open our Chat Window (we chatted a few days before I changed my number) in their phone and send a message, will the message be automatically redirected to my new number?

Assuming I never told anyone that I have changed my number.

Comment: The messages will be directed to your new number. I have experienced it. You will be notified in group chats. As for personal notifications I am not sure.

Answer (score -1):

People will be notified in groups, but not in private chats. All the messages will go to your new number.